# Convert CIDR to IP Ragnes mysql

Tags: mysql, ip, maxmind, cidr

I am using a maxmind test database. How may I generate the IP Range of something, given the network start and the network prefix length? I have a mysql table. In this, there are two columns labeled network_start_ip and network_prefix_length.
In the network_start_ip, some values look like ::ffff:1.0.64.0 , ::ffff:1.0.32.0 , and ::ffff:1.0.16.0.
The associated network prefix lengths are 114,115,and 116. How would I use these two columns, using some mysql command or statements, to generate IP ranges? I believe the aforementioned values are some sort of CIDR notation? Although I am not sure. So how may one generate an IP Range Notation from CIDR notation using mysql? By IP range... I mean that there is an IP_From and IP-To, such as 16777216 and 16777471, respectively.

Comment: You have [IPv6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6#Address_representation) addresses here.

Comment: What does that mean? I am relatively new to this and trying to understand. What specifically are you saying are IPv6 addresses?

Comment: You don't have IPv4 addresses and you don't have CIDR. You've got IPv6 addresses. I've linked to a description of address representations of IPv6.

Comment: Okay. I looked at the link. So the "::ffff:1.0.32.0" values and so on... those are IPv6 addresses. Is it POSSIBLE to convert these to the IP_froms and IP_tos... like I described... Basically...

Comment: 1. Is the network prefix length NECESSARY to make this conversion? And

Comment: 2. Is it POSSIBLE to convert IPv6 addresses to standard IP ranges? I may post another question so I'm not seeking a solution but rather to know if it's possible.

Comment: Please edit this question to adapt it to the new ones. Last one: no - it's the other way around, because IPv6 has a very much enhanced address room. There are ways to map an IPv4 address to an IPv6 address, see [linked article, section IPv4-mapped IPv6 addresses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6#IPv4-mapped_IPv6_addresses)